# How can I continue working on my code on another device?

Tags: azure, github, cloud, onedrive, sharing

I'm new to programming in general, and I'm currently working on a little game project in Python + pygame. One day I might want to work on my laptop, and the other day on my desktop.
How could I make it so that I can continue on my code from whatever computer I'll be working on?
You could compare it to working in the same document in Google Drive, from whatever device you want.
I've seen services like Github, Google Cloud Code, Microsoft Azure... could they be what I'm looking for?
Would it work storing my project folder in something like Microsoft Onedrive?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately there's really no single "right" answer to your question, and tool/product/service recommendation questions are off-topic (as they garner opinions, and sometimes spam). There are several popular version-control approaches, many of them based on git, and you've already mentioned one of them. There are also file-sync services (again, you've mentioned a few). I would suggest spending some time learning about what's available with version control options, as this will let you track your changes.

Comment: Also: If you have questions specific to file-sharing and syncing, that would fit better on SuperUser, not Stack Overflow (although, again, a recommendation for a given file-sync service would be off-topic there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub is exactly what you are looking for :)
Google: Version Control Systems

Comment: This would serve much better as a comment, rather than an answer. GitHub is one of many available version control options (and is already mentioned in the OP's question). There's no "right" answer to this, aside from opinions.